# How to divide two items in ASP.NET razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to divide two items like so:

```
<td>@item.Sum(m => m.stat.hits) / @item.Sum(m => m.stat.AB)</td>
```

but it just results this in text format like this

> 1197 / 3956

What am I doing wrong?

I am expecting the outcome .303

UPDATE

got it working by

```
<td>@Math.Round(Decimal.Divide(item.Sum(m => m.stat.hits), item.Sum(m => m.stat.AB)), 3)</td>
```

which returns 0.303

How do I remove the zero before the decimal?

Answer (score 2):

Pre-face this by saying I'm on my mobile device so please excuse any typos.

You need to encompass the operation with braces, like so:

```html
<td>@{ item.Sum(m => m.stat.hits) / item.Sum(m => m.stat.AB) }</td>
```

However the `Sum()` operation returns an integer so you may need to convert it into a `double` to display correctly.

That being said while this solution should give you the correct answer I would highly recommend simply adding the operation as a property on the object and accessing it instead of calculating it on the fly.

EDIT:
Couple of ways to remove leading zeroes. Casting to a string and calling `str.TrimStart('0')`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the curly brackets, you can do programming at razor view. Here is the sample code those you need to do for your solution.

```
   <td>
        @{ 
             double sumHits = item.Sum(m => m.stat.hits);
             double sumAb = item.Sum(m => m.stat.AB);
             double result = sumHits / sumAb;

             if (sumAb > 0)
                {
                    double result = sumHits / sumAb;
                    <Span>@result</Span>
                }
          }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy way:

```
  static void Main() {

  String str ="0.2354".TrimStart(new Char[] { '0','.' } );
  Console.WriteLine(str);
 }
```

For number `0.0000002354` it works correctly.